# Proximal Gradient Descent

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, python, proximal-operators

I am trying to solve the below optimization problem using proximal gradient descent on a dataset in python:

$f(\theta) = \arg\min_{\theta \in R^d}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m\Big [log(1+exp(x_i\theta))-y_ix_i\theta\Big]+\frac{\lambda_2}{2}||\theta||^2_2 + \lambda_1||\theta||_1$

where $x_i \in R^{1 \times d}$ is sample $i$, $\theta \in R^d$ and $y_i \in \{0,1\}$ is the label for sample $i$
and $\lambda>0$.

The gradient of $g(\theta)$ being

$\nabla g(\theta) = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m\Big[\frac{x_ie^{x\theta}}{1+e^{x_i\theta}} - x_iy_i\Big]+\theta \lambda_2$

The dataset contains 784 columns and 2000 datapoints half of which i use for learning $\theta$ and the remaining for evaluating accuracy of the classifier. The $\theta$ learnt is used to predict labels given by $\frac{1}{1+exp(-x\theta)}$. I need to build the classifier using proximal operators, and plot the accuracy per iteration.

This is the code i have come up with but my accuracy is way off, it is expected to converge with >98% accuracy in one to 5 iterations max.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
np.random.seed(100)
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv",header = None).values
A = data[:,0:784]
y = data[:,-1]
A_train = A[:1000,]
y_train = y[:1000,]
A_test = A[1000:,]
y_test = y[1000:,]
lam_1 = 10
lam_2 = 5
m = len(A_train)

def prox_op(theta,t):
    a = np.maximum(theta - t, 0)
    b = np.minimum(theta + t, 0)
    return a+b

def func(theta):
  func_sum = 0
  for i in range(m):
    func_sum += np.log(1+np.exp(A_train[i]*theta)) - y_train[i]*A_train[i]*theta
  term2 = lam_2/2 * np.linalg.norm(theta)
  term3 = lam_1 * np.linalg.norm([theta], ord = 1)
  return func_sum/m + term2 + term3

def grad(theta):
  for i in range(m):
    grad_sum = (A_train[i] * np.exp(A_train[i] * theta)/(1 + np.exp(A_train[i] * theta))) - (A_train[i] * y_train[i]) 
  return grad_sum + (theta * lam_2)

t = 0.01
iterations = 100
theta_new = np.random.uniform(-1,1,784)
theta_list = [theta_new]
func_list = [func(theta_new)]
acc_sc = []

for i in range(iterations-1):
    theta_current = theta_list[-1]
    grad_g = grad(theta_current) 
    theta_new_gd = theta_current - t * grad_g; 
    theta_new = prox_op(theta_new_gd,lam_1*t)
    theta_list.append(theta_new)
    func_list.append(func(theta_new))
    yy_tr = 1/(1+np.exp(np.dot(-A_train, theta_new)))
    acc_sc.append(accuracy_score(yy_tr>t*lam_1,y_train))

plt.plot(func_list)
plt.title('Proximal GD')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Function Value')
plt.show()
```

Could some one point where im going wrong please?

This is the plot of function value vs #iterations:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptMv3.png)

Comment: I’d like to see a out of the objective function value versus iteration number.

Comment: @littleO Have added the plot.

Comment: Thanks. That plot looks strange though. There should be only one objective finding value at each iteration.

Comment: Is it because I'm using * and not the numpy.dot function? When i try to substitute the multiplications with numpy.dot, the function values go to infinity though. May be some of the multiplications need to be substituted but im not sure which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing the proximal GD, you can (should ?) that your analytical gradient is correct. I suspect it should be

*** grad_sum +=  *** instead of
*** grad_sum = ***
since you are summing over the examples.
Also the normalisation term has disappeared...

Also you give the gradient but not the proximal update so this is not 'easy' to detect where your error is located.

Using slightly different notations,
denote
$$
\phi(\mathbf{w}) = 
g(\mathbf{w})
+ \lambda_1 \|\mathbf{w}\|_1 
$$
where
$g(\mathbf{w})
=\frac{1}{N}
\sum_{n=1}^N 
\left[ 
\log
\left(1+e_n\right) 
- y_n \mathbf{x}_n^T \mathbf{w}
\right]
+ \frac{\lambda_2}{2} \|\mathbf{w}\|^2_2 $ and the scalar
$e_n=\exp^{\mathbf{x}_n^T \mathbf{w}}$.

The update requires the soft-thresholding operator
$$
\mathbf{w} \leftarrow
S_{\lambda_1 t}
\left[
\mathbf{w}
-t \nabla g(\mathbf{w})
\right]
$$
where
$\nabla g(\mathbf{w})
=\frac{1}{N}
\sum_{n=1}^N 
\left[ 
\left(
\frac{e_n}{1+e_n}-y_n
\right)
\mathbf{x}_n
\right]
+ \lambda_2 \mathbf{w}
$.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! You are right, I missed to sum over all samples and the normalizing term. The remaining of it is same as what you have shown, the gradient and the soft thresholding operator. However, if you see the plot i posted, i'm off with the function computation, any flags you can see?

Comment: The plot seems incorrect to me since the objective function is a scalar. You have to check where the vector comes from and correct for it.